# Запятая между вопросами

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, вопросительный-знак

Поспорили с товарищем. Нужны ли вопросительные знаки после каждого вопроса в данной ситуации или можно их разделить запятой?

`Сколько вас таких в группе, есть в ее глазах тебе выгода?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дело в том, что "сколько" — слово многозначное:
[сколько](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE)
**I.** 1. Какое количество? Как много? *Сколько тебе лет? В скольких томах роман? По сколько рублей пришлось на каждого в зарплату?*
2. (*в восклиц. предл.*). Обозначает количество чего-либо; такое большое количество! так много! *Сколько прошло времени! Сколько лет, сколько зим!* (как давно не виделись) *Сколько воды утекло!* (как много времени прошло) *Сколько раз тебе говорить! Скольких поэтов повидал! А денег страсть сколько!*

Выражение "сколько вас таких" можно произнести с разной интонацией, и смыл от этого будет совершенно разным.

• **Вопросительная.** Какое количество? Сколько вас?
*И сколько вас таких по всему миру, несмышленых и остро нуждающихся в защите?* (Олег Дивов. Выбраковка).
*Сколько вас таких расторопных тут?* (М. А. Шолохов. Тихий Дон).

• **Восклицательная.** Как вас много! Вас так много!
*...ребята, сколько вас таких, а я один, и мне, может, всего-то полгода осталось летать* (В. В. Ершов. Дневник).
*Сколько вас таких было , и сколько еще вас таких будет...* (Г. Павленко. Жизнь. Перезагрузка).

•• Хотите, чтобы вас правильно поняли?

Тогда используйте два вопросительных знака, если предполагается первый смысл:
*Сколько вас таких в группе? Есть в ее глазах тебе выгода?*
[Смысл второго вопроса я, правда, не совсем понимаю.]

И восклицательный — если второй:
*Сколько вас таких в группе! Есть в ее глазах тебе выгода?*

Answer (score 1):

Как я думаю, правильно написать так:

***Сколько** вас таких в группе и **есть ли**, в ее глазах, тебе выгода?*

Используем союз ***И*** и вопросительную частицу ***ЛИ***. Это ССП, объединяющим общим элементом будет **вопросительная интонация**.

***В ее глазах*** — вводное обособленное сочетание.